# powercfg returns different results depending on 32-bit vs. 64-bit version

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wow64, powercfg

I was trying to call [powercfg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) tool from my 32-bit application running on a 64-bit version of Windows 8.1 using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) with the following command as `lpCommandLine` parameter:

```
"powercfg -waketimers"
```

It worked fine, except that purely by chance I discovered that it was returning a different looking report than if I ran the same from the `Command Line` window.

Here's what I was getting in my 32-bit process:

```
Timer set by [PROCESS] Legacy Kernel Caller expires at 4:00:02 AM on 1/20/2016.
Reason: 

Timer set by [PROCESS] Legacy Kernel Caller expires at 3:59:00 AM on 1/20/2016.
Reason:
```

and here's what I was seeing in `Command Line` window:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 4:00:02 AM on 1/20/2016.
Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.

Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\Schedule2\schedul2.exe (AcrSch2Svc) expires at 3:59:00 AM on 1/20/2016.
```

So I'm curious, are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of that tool supposed to return different results? Because the only way I can remedy this and get a full report (2nd version above) from my 32-bit process is to detect it running as WOW64 and then use the following path for a forced 64-bit redirect:

```
"C:\\Windows\\SysWow64\\powercfg.exe -waketimers"
```